# Objective-C equivalent of Java's LinkedBlockingQueue<Long>

Tags: ios, objective-c, linked-list

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and I have to implement a `LinkedBlockingQueue` with Objective-C.

I have to do something like this code:

```
public boolean onEvent(final EventArgs e) {

    if (e.getClass() != this.eventType) return false;

    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    long diff = now - this.last;

    final long threadExecutionTimeMs = now - lastThreadExecution;

    if (executions.remainingCapacity() == 0)
    {
        executions.poll();
    }

    executions.add(threadExecutionTimeMs);

   ...
}
```

Probably I can use `NSMutableArray` but I don't know how to emulate blocking, etc.

**Any advice?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no equivalent AFAIK, you'll need to roll your own.

I think I'd probably use a [dispatch semaphore](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24).

Create a class with an instance variable that is the list of items in the queue (`NSMutableArray` is probably a good candidate).  The class should also have an instance variable that is a dispatch semaphore.
In `-init` initialise the array and the semaphore with an initial count of zero.

Create two methods, one to enqueue an element and one to dequeue an element.  The enqueue must also signal the semaphore *after* adding the element. The dequeue must wait on the semaphore *before* removing the element.

The code would look something like this:

```
@implementation MyQueue
{
    NSMutableArray* myArray;
    dispatch_semaphore_t fd_sema;
}

-(void) enqueue (id) anObject
{
    @synchronized(myArray)
    {
        [myArray addObject: anObject];
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(fd_sema);
}

-(id) dequeue
{
     dispatch_semaphore_wait(fd_sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
     id ret = nil;
     @synchronized(myArray)
     {
         ret = [myArray objectAtIndex: 0];
         [myArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
     }
     return ret;
}
```

The semaphore effectively counts the number of objects in the array.  `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` increments the semaphore.  `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` decrements the semaphore unless it's already zero, in which case the thread stops until something else signals the semaphore.

Accesses to the array itself are synchronized because a) there would otherwise be a race condition on removing something from the queue and b) I can't be bothered to look up whether  NSMutableArray is thread safe.